# Let V be the vector space consisting of all nxn matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T:V →V be a linear transformation such that Ker{T}=V. If I is the identity nxn matrix, what is T(I)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $\ker(T)=V$, $T:I\to 0$, i.e., $T(I)=0$, the zero element in $V$.

Comment: thank you so much for help....never had anyone answer me right away :D

Comment: @user131057 The question was easy and thus I answered it immediately...

Comment: @user131057 Please do read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer. If this answer was what you wanted, click on the green check mark next to the answer to mark this question as answered.

Comment: still it is not that easy for me but thank you so much :D

Comment: @user131057 Sure! Of course, I hope you read the above comment of mine, since I have observed that none of your questions have accepted answers.

Comment: yes and i hope i used the options right :D